# Joining multiple Linksys SRW208P

Tags: linksys, switch

I've got a question about the Linksys SRW208P that I can't find a straight answer to on the net.

If I have 2 of the SRW208P that I want to connect on the same simple network - so that 16 people can connect instead of just 8, do I just connect a LAN cable between the 2 gig ports on the switchs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But you will actually have 14 people connecting instead of 16 because one port on each switch is used as an uplink.

Because it is gigabit, you don't need to use any special uplink port or crossover cable. Just plug in and go.

Comment: If you really want 16 ports, then you'll have to find two mini-gbics (often fibre ones but you can also get "normal" ones) and use that to do the uplink instead. [Something like this](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/Genuine-Linksys-1000-BASE-T-Mini-GBIC-SFP-Transceiver-/390220434592?cmd=ViewItem&pt=AU_Computers_Networking_Accessories&hash=item5adaf34ca0).

Comment: How many of these switches can you have linked together? Maximum 2? What I'd like to know is if I can use the 2 RJ-45/miniGBIC combo ports to connect multiple instances of this switch together. Thanks.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to have the network diagram like this:

Server ----(Gigabit)---->mini-gbic port(1)

then:

mini-gbic(2) ----> mini-gbic(switch2, mini-gbic1)

Comment: Now I'm confused. Looking at a detailed picture of it, there are 8 ports at 10/100, 2 gigabit ports, and 2 minigbic ports...

Comment: @Newbie, 1) You can link as many of them as you like, 2) If you have 8+2, then do the uplink using the gigabit ports, as then you won't run into any bandwidth bottlenecks (8x100Mb < 1x1Gb), and then you also get 16 ports. Bonus.

Comment: So, just to be 100%. I will use the 8x100mb for PCs. I will use 1 of the 1Gb ports to connect to one of the 1Gb ports on the second switch to make it a total of 16x100mb.

Comment: @Newbie, correct